# After the submit is clicked, the input is not submitted in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code has 2 classes which are "Forum" and PostEditor". When the button "Post" is clicked which is in the "PostEditor" class, the textarea which has the state "newPostBody" is submitted but the input which has the state "newTitle" is not submitted in ReactJs. Below there is an image of it. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
    const Post = props => (
        <div>
            <div >{props.postBody}</div>
        </div>
    );

    class PostEditor extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                newPostBody: '',
                newTitle: ''
            };
        }

        handleInputChange(ev) {
            this.setState({
                newPostBody: ev.target.value
            });
        }
        handleTitleChange(ev) {
            this.setState({
                newTitle: ev.target.value
            });
        }

        createPost() {
            this.props.addPost(this.state.newPostBody, this.state.newTitle);
            this.setState({
                newPostBody: '',
                newTitle: ''
            });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text"   value={this.state.newTitle}
                               onChange={this.handleTitleChange.bind(this)}/>
                        <textarea  value={this.state.newPostBody}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} />
                        <button onClick={this.createPost.bind(this)}
                            disabled={!this.state.newPostBody} > Post </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }


class Forum extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: [],
        };
    }

    addPost(newPostBody) {
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        newState.posts.push(newPostBody);
        this.setState(newState);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.posts.map((postBody, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <div >
                            <Post key={idx} postBody={postBody} />
                        </div>);
                })}
                <PostEditor addPost={this.addPost.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addPost` method in Forum class is only expecting body and not expecting 2nd argument which I guess would be title:

You should update it with something like below:

```
class Forum extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: [],
        };
    }

    addPost(newPostBody, newPostTitle) {
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        let post = {body: newPostBody, title: newPostTitle}
        newState.posts.push(post);
        this.setState(newState);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.posts.map((post, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <div >
                            <Post key={idx} postBody={post.body} postTitle={post.title} />
                        </div>);
                })}
                <PostEditor addPost={this.addPost.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Post.js

```
 const Post = props => (
        <div>
           <div> {props.postTitle} </div>
           <div> {props.postBody} </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like in your `addPost` function after clicking the Post button, you are not receiving the same params as the arguments you provided from the `createPost`:

```
createPost() {
            this.props.addPost(this.state.newPostBody, this.state.newTitle); <== 2 args
            this.setState({
                newPostBody: '',
                newTitle: ''
            });
        }
```

vs

```
addPost(newPostBody) { <== 1 arg only
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        newState.posts.push(newPostBody);
        this.setState(newState);
    }
```

I think you want to make the call to `addPost` look like: `this.props.addPost({body: this.state.newPostBody, title: this.state.newTitle})`

Then you will have to update the `Post` UI to handle both `title` and `body` values.